# Saving a file and automatically create directories

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I am concatenating a number of variables and I want to save that string as a file path.

Is there a way it will automatically create all appropriate directories if they don't exist without having to check "if exists" on each one

For example.

```
"C:\" + a + "\" + b+ "\" + d + "\" + d + ".txt"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a folder does not exist, create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `new FileInfo(path).Directory.Create()`.

(This creates anything in the hierarchy that's required. If the directory already exists it does nothing.)

Comment: As you can not be sure to find a FileInfo for the path I would add a conditional access:   `new FileInfo(destFileName).Directory?.Create();`

Comment: @DaveM: Can you give an example where `FileInfo.Directory` will return null? I'm not sure what you mean by "can not be sure to find a FileInfo for the path", but in at least some failure cases, an exception will be thrown rather than returning null - I can't see any documentation for cases where this will return null.

Comment: Yes ur absolutely right. Sorry I made a mistake here. As you mentioned the docs say: _DirectoryNotFoundException_ ... when 
_The specified path is invalid, such as being on an unmapped drive_. There does not seem to be a case `FileInfo.Directory` will return null

Answer (score 15):

```
using System.IO;
....
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\temp\a\b\c\d\e");
```

Comment: Don't forget an if (Directory.Exists(...) check.

Comment: @ProfK no need to check if directory exists, **Directory.CreateDirectory()** already does that