# System.IO.File.Move error - Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, file-move

I have a sync software, which loads CSV files from "Incoming" folder, processes them and then moves them to the "Archive" folder.

Today, I saw the following error with this sync software:

> [23/06/2014 00:06:04 AM] : Failed to move file from
>
> D:\IBI_ORDER_IMPORTER_FTP_SERVER\Template3\Fifty &
> Dean\Incoming\5A040K___d6f1ca45937b4ceb98d29d0db4601bf4.csv to
>
> D:\IBI_ORDER_IMPORTER_FTP_SERVER\Template3\Fifty &
> Dean\Archive\5A040K___d6f1ca45937b4ceb98d29d0db4601bf4.csv - **Could not
> find a part of the path**.

Here's a snippet taken out of the sync software, where the file is processed and moved:

```
public static void ProcessSingleUserFile(Int32 TemplateId, String ImportedBy, String FilePath)
{
    // Always Rename File To Avoid Conflict
    string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FilePath);
    String NewFilePath = FilePath.Replace(FileName, Utils.RandomString() + "___" + FileName);
    File.Move(FilePath, NewFilePath);
    FilePath = NewFilePath;

    // Log
    SyncUtils.ConsoleLog(String.Format("Processing [ {0} as {1} ] By [ {2} ] On Template [ #{3} ]",
        FileName + ".csv",
        Path.GetFileName(FilePath),
        ImportedBy,
        TemplateId));

    // Init
    List<OrderDraft> myOrderDrafts = new List<OrderDraft>();

    // Parsed Based On Template Id
    if (TemplateId == Settings.Default.Multi_Order_Template_Id)
    {
        // Try Parse File
        myOrderDrafts = Utils.ParseMultiImportFile(TemplateId, ImportedBy, FilePath, true);
    }
    else
    {
        // Try Parse File
        myOrderDrafts.Add(Utils.ParseImportFile(TemplateId, ImportedBy, FilePath, true));
    }

    // Process Orders
    foreach (OrderDraft myOrderDraft in myOrderDrafts)
    {
        /* code snipped */
    }

    // Archive File
    File.Move(FilePath, FilePath.Replace("Incoming", "Archive"));
}
```

Any idea what this error means? and how to circumvent it?

---

I wrote a cut down version of the above to test this in a controlled environment and I am not getting the error with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string baseDir = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FTP_SERVER\Template3\Fifty & Dean\Incoming\";

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(baseDir, "*.csv");

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            // do some work here ...

            // move file
            string newFilePath = filePath.Replace("Incoming", "Archive");
            File.Move(filePath, newFilePath);
            Console.WriteLine("File successfully moved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: On what line did the error occur? Did you verify the path exists?

Comment: Is the path modified by at least a single character? If you are on a shared/corporate network, did you see any permission changes to the folder?

Comment: Utils.RandomString(), is there a possibility that it is putting in invalid path chars?

Comment: @Matthijs Yes the path exists. @SivaGopal the file movement is local, not over the network. the sync software is on `D` drive and that's where all the folders and files are. @KevinCook that function only returns alpha-numeric values.

Comment: Is the D drive a usb or removable drive?  Before the move, just try a Directory.Exists( Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath)) to make sure its correct.  Do you have any backup or other software running which might lock or cause drive access problems?

Comment: `D` drive is a secondary hard drive (1TB) not a usb drive. No other software has access to this folder on D drive. I'll add the `DriveExists()` check in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the checks to make sure that the paths exist at runtime and check the output, something very simple like:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
{
   Console.WriteLine("filePath does not exist: " + filePath);
}

if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath)))
{
   Console.WriteLine("newFilePath does not exist: " + newFilePath);
}
File.Move(filePath, newFilePath);
```

The reason I am suggesting this method is due to a possibility that the paths momentarily become available or not under the multi-tasking OSs depending on a multitude of factors: network connectivity, permissions (pushed down by GPO at any time), firewall rules, AV exclusions getting blown away etc. Even running low on CPU or RAM may create issues. In short, you never know what exactly occurred when your code was running if you are only checking the paths availability after the fact.

Or if your issue is intermittent, you can try and catch the error and write information to some sort of a log similarly to below:

```
try
{
    File.Move(filePath, newFilePath);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("filePath does not exist: " + filePath);
    }

    if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath)))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("newFilePath does not exist: " + newFilePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**"Could not find a part of the path"** exception could also thrown from `File.Move` if argument used was longer than MAX_PATH (260) in .NET Framework.

So I prepend the path I used with long path syntax before passing to `File.Move` and it worked.

```
// Prepend long file path support
if( !packageFile.StartsWith( @"\\?\" ) )
    packageFile = @"\\?\" + packageFile;
```

See:
[How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters)

Comment: For me this was the case. The file path was too long.

Answer (score 0):

I have this

Could not find a part of the path

happened to me  when I

```
File.Move(mapfile_path , Path.Combine(newPath, mapFile));
```

.  After some testing, I find out our server administrator has blocked any user application from writing to that directory in that [newPath]!

So, right click on that directory to observe the rights matrix on Security tab to see anything that would block you.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of DirectoryNotFoundException "could not find a part of the path" thrown by File.Move can be spaces at the end of the directory name. Consider the following code:

```
string destinationPath = "C:\\Folder1 ";        //note the space on the end
string destinationFileNameAndPath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, "file.txt");

if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

File.Move(sourceFileNameAndPath, destinationFileNameAndPath);
```

You may expect this code to succeed, since it creates the destination directory if it doesn't already exist, but Directory.CreateDirectory seems to trim the extra space on the end of the directory name, whereas File.Move does not and gives the above exception.

In this circumstance, you can workaround this by trimming the extra space yourself, e.g. (depending on how you load your path variable, the below is obviously overkill for a hard-coded string)

```
string destinationPath = "C:\\Folder1 ".Trim();
```