# Removing and listing directories above the character limit

Tags: python, windows, directory

I created a directory above the character limit adding "\\?\" before the directory, but I can't delete it using `shutil.rmtree` or list it using `os.walk`.

I get the following error with `shutil.rmtree("folder")`:

> WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'folder\CAAAAAAAAAB2iMan9VH4-0fxO4JOiT43bz9XVbQUoCcdOJTk1WRcPA++\BwAAAAAAAACXEWzr-_xJujcfpbaeAa-zNMqou1c_EtOH1lGXEMaL8w++\CAAAAAAAAACq0GkU9kGYNVDcaXAZ78ut8FSHTvE45Ra69qN495R6Fw++\CgAAAAAAAAAsOJ6oX-y6iRcg2F3KB4HGi6kcWnU2QPO2CEKsJUA4-g++'

Is there a function I can use to remove that directory?

Thanks.

Comment: To list or remove a long path, you need to use the absolute path as a unicode string, e.g. `shutil.rmtree(ur"\\?\C:\some\long\path\folder")`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) and also with more detail from links on the page linked to by [ivan_pozdeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648265/ivan-pozdeev), the solution is summarized below:

**Given a path which is longer than 260 characters long, `shutil.rmtree` cannot remove the file.**

Let's assume

`directory = "some path that is more than 260 characters"`.

An attempt to `shutil.rmtree(directory)` will fail with a `*** WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "some path that is more than 260 characters"` error.  It is not clear that the file exists and that the path length is the real problem.

**The solution is to prepend `\\?\` to the path** which I do for arbitrary paths thusly:

```
shutil.rmtree(ur'\\?\ '.strip()+ directory, onerror=onerror)
```

Note that even when using the `r''` syntax, the string may not end with a slash, so I solve this by adding a space and then `strip()`-ing the string.

This link was where it all became clear to me: https://github.com/nerdvegas/rez/issues/436

Comment: Can you explain what `ur'\\?\'` is supposed to do?

Comment: @ErikusMaximus As xobes says, this is a special symbol combination in Windows saying that the following path and each of its parts may be longer than 256 symbols.

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś Is this documented somewhere in the official Python documentation?  If so, can you provide a link?

Comment: @ErikusMaximus It is documented, but it's not a Python property, but a Windows property. So the official documentation is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation and you can read more about it in this SE post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after prefixing '\\?\' also had not helped, for me it was wrong delimiter in path, a combination of both forward slash and backward slash can cause it. For me it got fixed when I replaced forward slash (/) with backward slash (\).