# Bug edit document with long patch on ajaxbrowser/Ajax Library

Tags: ithit-ajax-file-browser

I'm working with Ajax library to online edit a document. I have a problem when edit a document have long path.
The exception is "**Could not mount webdav server, please verify provided credentials**". I'm search is bug of davfs2 on ubuntu [davfs2 bug](https://bugs.dogfood.paddev.net/ubuntu/+source/davfs2/+bug/1288869)

The bug come from path of document is too long. 
IMO, ITHit can hash a document. Please don't wait davfs2 bug above is fixed.

Please confirm this bug for me & talk to me a workaround in this case :) when waiting a new fix patch on new library

Answer (score 0):

Ajax File Browser and WebDAV Ajax Library does not have any limitations on path length. Internally both Ajax File Browser and WebDAV Ajax Library use davfs2 on Linux, unfortunately currently there is no way to avoid using it.

In case you are using WebDAV server running .NET Framework with file system back-end, you may experience the 'Path Too Long' .NET Framework issue. Please find more information here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx

[How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters)

Note that the IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine itself does not have any limitations on path length too.