# IT HIT webdav server for filesystem no working with max file path

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I need some details related to WebDav server implementation. Currently I have integrated webdav server for filesystem with basic authentication schema with my web application. Is web dav server working with max file path? As I am having file at path length 420 but i am facing issue with it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET itself does not have any limitations on file path. The limitation is in the WebDAV server implementation and in case of the file system sample in .NET Framework.

The most simple way to achieve long file path support is to build a server that runs on .NET Core. To generate the WebDAV server that runs on .NET Core you can either use the [ASP.NET Core WebDAV Server Application](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards/) wizard:

[image]

or use [WebDAVServer.FileSystemStorage.AspNetCore](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/cross_platform_asp_net_core_file_system/) sample provided with SDK.

You can also achieve long file path support with a regular .NET Framework, but this will require more affords: [How to deal with files with a name longer than 259 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters)