# DirectoryInfo.create DirectoryNotFoundException instead of PathTooLongException

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

`DirectoryInfo.Create` is throwing `DirectoryNotFoundException` when the path is longer than 260 characters. I understand that it is not possible to create the directory, but the method also supports `PathTooLongException`. Why isn't it thrown instead? When the path's lenght is >248 and <260 a `PathTooLongException` is thrown. Shouldn't both cases throw the same exception?

My code:

```
DirectoryInfo fullArchiveDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullArchiveDirectory);
fullArchiveDirectoryInfo.Create();
```

My project targets .NET Framework 4.6.2.

(Update 1)

For example:

- C:(...)-9223372036854775808\86dcadfc1e0746649408 - 264 characters - `DirectoryNotFoundException`
- C:(...)-9223372036854775808\86dcadfc1e074664 - 260 characters - `PathTooLongException`
- C:(...)-9223372036854775808\f872 - 248 characters - no exception

Additional note: I tested with LinqPad (v5.31.00) and there I always get a `PathTooLongException` with a path 264 characters long.

Comment: So if you use a path with length 250 (for example) you get a `PathTooLongException`?

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException when path is longer than 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409118/system-io-directorynotfoundexception-when-path-is-longer-than-260-characters)

Comment: I voted to close this question as duplicated, event though I still think the most correct exception would be `PathTooLongException`.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.

Invalid path, such as unmapped drives, will thrown `DirectoryNotFoundException` despite of how long is the `path`.

Check the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,e3885fef9f6af9de),

Comment: Yes, you are right, but only reducing the size of the path (last folder's name) until I reach 260 characters long, I get a `PathTooLongException`.