# Get file owner from Robocopy created text file, output in CSV with full path and owner. Paths longer that 256 characters

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, hashtable, robocopy

I have created a script that uses Robocopy to create a txt file with the full path of every file on a drive (~5 million objects).  I then import that file into a foreach loop and downloaded the module that will allow large file paths (get-ntfsowner) that will iterate through the file paths and spit out the file path and owner in a CSV.  I'm then using that file to run another script our support center will use that will plug all of this in to subinacl to change all the user's file ownerships to their manager when the user leaves the company.

The script runs perfectly, but the problem is finding the owner and creating the CSV's take a few days.  I found that maybe hashtables may help me but I'm pretty much lost on this.  I'm also thinking get-acl would be much faster but I run into the 256 character limit and have spent hours trying to get \?\ to work with no success.   I'm pretty sure my bottleneck though is the foreach loops slowing things down.

Can someone help me take this code and make it much more efficient?  I'm trying to get it down to where it will run in an overnight window every night.

```
#Gets Owner for each file And Create CSV
$Dir = "D:\AutoAssign\Data\RoboLogs"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Dir
ForEach ($File in $Files){ Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Dir,$Files,$File)

$OutputFile = "D:\AutoAssign\Data\Final\$File.csv"
$Results = @()

$Paths = Get-Content $Dir\$File
ForEach ($Path in $Paths){
 $Owner = get-ntfsowner $Path | Select Owner | ft -hidetableheaders | Out-String
 $Owner = $Owner.Trim()

      $Properties = @{

      Path = $Path
      Owner = $Owner

      }

If ($Owner -ne "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $Owner -ne $null-and $Owner -ne "Domain\Domain Admins" -and $Owner -notlike "S-1*"){
    $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties}

    }


$Results | Export-Csv -notypeinformation -Path $OutputFile

} -ArgumentList $Dir,$Files,$File #Ends Initial ForEach

}  #Ends Job Script Block
```

Comment: If you have working code you're looking to improve, you should ask on [codereview.se] instead. It's what it was created to do.

Comment: Retrieving ACL from so many files may just be an expensive operation. Is this script accessing network paths? If so, you might try to run it directly on the file server.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm running it from the server on a local drive.  I'll ask on Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may help you at all, considering you have so many file to process..
In case you do need to call the Windows APIs directly like Mehrdad explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters#39534444), you could try incorporating the code below and use that instead of the `get-ntfsowner` to see if it works any faster.

Also I would suggest putting this part of your code

```
$Properties = @{
  Path = $Path
  Owner = $Owner
}
```

one line down, so just after the

```
If ($Owner -ne "BUILTIN\Administrators" -and $Owner -ne $null-and $Owner -ne "Domain\Domain Admins" -and $Owner -notlike "S-1*")
```

It won't do much of course, but it saves you from creating a hash when it is not needed.
Maybe the test itself can be tidied up a bit, for instance something like:

```
If (($Owner) -and $Owner -notmatch '^(BUILTIN\\|NT AUTHORITY\\|S-1).+|(.+\\Domain Admins)$')
```

Anyway, here's the code using Win32 api to overcome the 260 character limit of Get-Ace

```
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'Win32Api.LongFileName').Type) {
    Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
    using System.Security.Principal;

    namespace Win32Api {
        public static class LongFileName
        {
            internal const uint ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;

            internal const int INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES  = -1;
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY  = 0x1;      // A file that is read-only. This attribute is not honored on directories.
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN    = 0x2;      // The file or directory is hidden. It is not included in an ordinary directory listing.
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM    = 0x4;      // A file or directory that the operating system uses a part of, or uses exclusively.
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL    = 0x80;     // A file that does not have other attributes set. This attribute is valid only when used alone.
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x10;     // The handle that identifies a directory.
            internal const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE   = 0x20;     // A file or directory that is an archive file or directory.
            internal const int FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES     = 0x0080;
            internal const int FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES    = 0x0100;

            internal const int FILE_READ_DATA           = 0x0001;
            internal const int FILE_WRITE_DATA          = 0x0002;
            internal const int FILE_APPEND_DATA         = 0x0004;
            internal const int FILE_READ_EA             = 0x0008;
            internal const int FILE_WRITE_EA            = 0x0010;

            internal const int FILE_SHARE_NONE          = 0x00000000;
            internal const int FILE_SHARE_READ          = 0x00000001;

            internal const long READ_CONTROL            = 0x00020000L;
            internal const long STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ    = READ_CONTROL;
            internal const long STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE   = READ_CONTROL;
            internal const long SYNCHRONIZE             = 0x00100000L;

            internal const long FILE_GENERIC_WRITE = STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE |
                                                     FILE_WRITE_DATA |
                                                     FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES |
                                                     FILE_WRITE_EA |
                                                     FILE_APPEND_DATA |
                                                     SYNCHRONIZE;

            internal const long FILE_GENERIC_READ = STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ |
                                                    FILE_READ_DATA |
                                                    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES |
                                                    FILE_READ_EA |
                                                    SYNCHRONIZE;


            internal const int CREATE_NEW    = 1;
            internal const int CREATE_ALWAYS = 2;
            internal const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

            internal const int MAX_PATH      = 260;
            internal const int MAX_ALTERNATE = 14;

            enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
            {
                SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE,
                SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                SE_SERVICE,
                SE_PRINTER,
                SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
                SE_LMSHARE,
                SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
                SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
                SE_DS_OBJECT,
                SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
                SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
                SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
                SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
            }
            enum SECURITY_INFORMATION
            {
                OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 1,
                GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 2,
                DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 4,
                SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 8,
            }

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern uint GetSecurityInfo(IntPtr handle, SE_OBJECT_TYPE objectType, SECURITY_INFORMATION securityInfo, out IntPtr sidOwner, out IntPtr sidGroup, out IntPtr dacl, out IntPtr sacl, out IntPtr securityDescriptor);

            [DllImport("advapi32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            static extern bool ConvertSidToStringSid(IntPtr sid, out IntPtr sidString);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            static extern int GetFileAttributesW(string lpFileName);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern IntPtr LocalFree(IntPtr handle);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
            static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
            static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

            public static string GetFileOwner(string filename)
            {
                IntPtr fileHandle;
                IntPtr ownerSid;
                IntPtr groupSid;
                IntPtr dacl;
                IntPtr sacl;
                IntPtr securityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
                uint result = 0;

                try
                {
                    fileHandle = GetFileHandle(filename);
                    result = GetSecurityInfo(fileHandle, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, SECURITY_INFORMATION.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, out ownerSid, out groupSid, out dacl, out sacl, out securityDescriptor);
                    IntPtr ptrString = IntPtr.Zero;
                    bool success = ConvertSidToStringSid(ownerSid, out ptrString);
                    string strSid = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptrString);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrString);

                    // convert the user sid string to a domain\name. Needs .NET 2.0 or better
                    string account = new SecurityIdentifier(strSid).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account))
                    {
                        return account;  // domain\user
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine("Could not translate SID to username. User may have been deleted.");
                        return strSid;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    LocalFree(securityDescriptor);
                    // If you use a SafeFileHandle, do not call CloseHandle as the CLR will close it for you (even if it's already closed).
                    // CloseHandle(fileHandle);
                }
            }

            public static IntPtr GetFileHandle(string filename)
            {
                if (filename.Length >= MAX_PATH) filename = AddLongPathPrefix(filename);
                SafeFileHandle hfile = CreateFile(filename, (int)FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hfile.IsInvalid) ThrowWin32Exception();
                return hfile.DangerousGetHandle();
            }

            public static string AddLongPathPrefix(string path)
            {
                if (path.StartsWith(@"\\?\")) return path;

                var newpath = path;
                if (newpath.StartsWith("\\"))
                {
                    newpath = @"\\?\UNC\" + newpath.Substring(2);
                }
                else if (newpath.Contains(":"))
                {
                    newpath = @"\\?\" + newpath;
                }
                else
                {
                    var currdir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                    newpath = CombinePath(currdir, newpath);
                    while (newpath.Contains("\\.\\")) newpath = newpath.Replace("\\.\\", "\\");
                    newpath = @"\\?\" + newpath;
                }
                return newpath.TrimEnd('.');
            }

            public static string CombinePath(string path1, string path2)
            {
                return path1.TrimEnd('\\') + "\\" + path2.TrimStart('\\').TrimEnd('.');
            }

            public static bool Exists(string path)
            {
                if (path.Length < MAX_PATH) return System.IO.File.Exists(path);
                var attr = GetFileAttributesW(AddLongPathPrefix(path));
                return (attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && (((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE) || 
                                                            ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)));
            }

            private static void ThrowWin32Exception()
            {
                int code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (code != 0)
                {
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(code);
                }
            }
        }
    }
"@
}

function Get-FileOwner {
    # Returns the owner of a file as string.
    # The script can handle both 'normal' path lengths aswell as Long paths (up to approx. 32760 characters)
    # The returned string MAY contain names such as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" or "BUILTIN\Administrators"
    # so you will have to exclude those afterwards if need be. When a string in the form of a SID string like
    # "S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-1013" is returned, it usually means the user has already been deleted.
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Path
    )
    if ([Win32Api.LongFileName]::Exists($Path)) {
        return [Win32Api.LongFileName]::GetFileOwner($Path)
    }
    Write-Warning "Path not found '$Path'"
}
```

This script was built based on information gathered from multiple places, but especially by adapting the code from [Wolf5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters#39534444)

Comment: This is great, speeding it up just by a little is huge.  Thanks so much!