# Could not find a part of the path while using File.Copy c# .net 4.7.2

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code just to copy a file from a smaller filepath into a longer file path (> 260 characters).

```
string dbCDataPath = Path.Combine(DYRECTORY_WITH_GUARANTEE_ACCESS,Path.GetFileName(pathFileName));
string targetFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathFileName), Path.GetFileName(pathFileName));
                    
File.Copy(dbCDataPath, targetFile, true);
```

I'm getting Could not find a part of the path error and I don't know why I have double checked both the source and the destination folders, both exists.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `DYRECTORY_WITH_GUARANTEE_ACCESS` a relative (`..\dir`) or absolute path (`C:\dir`)?

Comment: is absolute, like "C:\\Data\\"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call File.Copy like this:

```
File.Copy(targetFile, dbCDataPath, true);
```

The first parameter of this method is sourceFile you want to copy, the second parameter is destination path.

Comment: But I want to copy the file from dbCDataPath in targetFile.

Comment: What is the value of pathFileName string?

Comment: C:\\Data\\Sandboxes\\AA-PP\\30_PRJ\\30_FND\\BBBB_S4\\40_SW\\30_Module_Test\\20_TRTPckTst\\10_Testcases\\New\\AA_PP_RRRRR_BBBB_S4_CfgPck_TestCases\\AA_PP_RRRRR_BBBB_S4_CfgPck_TestCases\\test_cases\\newFolderr\\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\ccccccccccccccc\\ddddddddddddddd\\tttttttttt.bak, taken from vs debug, it is a path > 260 characters

Comment: Did you enable long path in windows?
If not, follow this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd

Comment: You can check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188527/how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters

Comment: Well I've tried to add <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/></startup>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false" />
  </runtime> in the app.config but the error is still there

Comment: I didn't perform any changes on windows, because I would like to achive the following use case , any user of the c# application shall be able to copy a file in another folder no matter how long the path is