# How to Create A File Even If Sub-Directories Dont Exist

Tags: c#, file-io

How can I create a file even if the some sub-directories dont exist? I am aware of this [Question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201598/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-any-folders-if-the-folders-dont-exist) that suggests I use `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` to create both my file and its directories.

But when I attempt to create my file using `Directory.CreateDirectory(path)` it creates the file as a directory/folder and not as a file?

[image]

```
Directory.CreateDirectory (@"C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalLow\company\product\database.db");
```

Why is `database.db` a folder and not a file? Am I doing something wrong? **How can I create a file even if the some sub-directories dont exist?**

Comment: Your question is the same as the one you've linked to, but you're using your full filename instead of the folder name.

Comment: In fairness, the question is a duplicate of the marked one, but the OP is correct in complaining that the accepted answer doesn't address their issue.

Comment: On second thoughts, I've reopened. The *title* of the question is a duplicate; the question itself is clearly a follow-up on the accepted answer from the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the *directory* path to the `CreateDirectory` method, not the full file path. You can extract this from the full path using [`GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalLow\company\product\database.db";
string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);   
                 // gives @"C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalLow\company\product"

Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
File.Create(filePath);   // can use any file API call here, such as File.Open
```