# Create Directory will multiple names passed by parameter C#

Tags: c#, directory

I have to create multiple folders as e.g.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("PATH\\" + _year + "filetosave.txt");
```

while `"PATH\\"` is the full path where the folder will reside, `_year` is the parameter and `"filetosave.txt"` is the file which is to be saved in respective folder.
And at run time, it should create respective folders with years in the folder name containing respective files to save.

Whereas `.CreateDirectory()` method only accepts `string path` or `string path, security access` as parameters.

- How will we create these parameterized folders?
- How can we make a check that a specified directory already exists or not?

Comment: In general, use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to build paths.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("Path\\", DateTime.Now.Year, "filetosave.txt"));` ?

Comment: See this thread for creating a method that will create the directory and file at the same time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201598/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-any-folders-if-the-folders-dont-exist If you want to create for multiple years, put this in a foreach look or use a Linq lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, use `Path.Combine` when trying to build system paths:

```
var root = "Path";
var year = "2016";
var filename = "filetosave.txt";

var path = Path.Combine(root, year, filename);
//  path = Path\2016\filetosave.txt

Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: @Jonesopolis--if the years are passed in a loop, then how will we handle? As years are not to be defined manually each time!

Comment: i dont understand how that causes any sort of problem.  You'd just loop over your years and create a directory for each one.  This was meant to be an example of building a dynamic path.

Comment: Right its mean the `var = year` if passed as a parameter in a loop, it'll work fine

Comment: @Jonesopolis--`Path.Combine()` method has some invalid arguments. The error raised.

Comment: You're probably passing an `int year` as an argument.  It takes strings.  I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Yeah obviously, I just changed it to `_year.ToString()`, now it worked

Comment: So, what for another question I just added that how can we have a check that specified directory already exists or not?

Comment: @Jonesopolis--How can we write text in these parameterized folders?

Answer (score 3):

```
var path = Path.Combine("PATH\\", _year.ToString(), "filettosave.txt");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

[Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates all directories **and subdirectories** in the specified path unless they already exist.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: @Sylverac--I think as you suggested `Path.Combine()` method, the parameter `_year` should be `_year.ToString()` as it only accepts stirngs

Answer (score 0):

In general, use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to build paths. It simplifies this task.

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, _year.ToString());
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
string file =  System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "filetosave.txt");
FileStream fs = File.Create(file)
```