# How to create/store xml file (made by serializer) in a certain directory?

Tags: c#

The code below creates XML file next to executable file of App.
However, I would like to have an XML file created in a certain folder next to the executable file.

For example (I want to get behaviour like this):

```
// same directory
App.exe
ParametersFolder (here lies Parameters.xml)
// same directory
```

The code I'm currently using

```
public static void Save()
{
  using (var file = File.Create(Singletone.FileName))
         formatter.Serialize(file, Singletone);
}
```

and deserialization

```
 public static void Load()
        {
            try
            {


                Parameters parameters;
                using (var file = File.OpenRead(Singletone.FileName))
                    parameters = (Parameters)formatter.Deserialize(file);

                Singletone.Text1 = parameters.Text1;
                Singletone.Text2 = parameters.Text2;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


                Singletone.Text1 = "first";

                Singletone.Text2 = "second";

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a folder to the file can be simply done by combining [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netcore-3.1), [Path.GetFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netcore-3.1) and [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netcore-3.1):

```
string oldPath = Singletone.FileName;
string folderToAdd = "ParametersFolder";

string newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(oldPath),
                              folderToAdd,
                              Path.GetFileName(oldPath));
```

Comment: and where do I have to put this code? please explain.

Comment: ```newPath``` replaces ```Singletone.FileName``` at your file creation.

Comment: the "ParametersFolder" do I have to create by myself in the App root directory?

Comment: If the folder is not existing yet, you need to do it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201598/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-any-folders-if-the-folders-dont-exist

Comment: And which way it will find out where to read that from, while deserialization?

Comment: How should I know this? That's a specific implemetnation detail you should know.

Comment: found by myself. now it works in both directions. Thanks a lot!