# How can i use FileSystemWatcher to watch directory if directory not exist?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

can any one help me to solve my problem below. I need to watch the file created inside the folder **"C:\Logs\CustomService\Testing"**. I am using the FileSystemWatcher to watch the files created inside it but how can i watch the folder **Testing** for the below cases

**case1:** only contain drive **C:\** how can i watch file created inside testing folder ?

**case2:** only contain following folder **C:\Logs** how can i watch file created inside testing folder ?

**case3:** only contain following folder **C:\Logs\CustomService**, How can i watch file created inside testing folder ?

**case4:** contian full path **C:\Logs\CustomService\Testing** , in this case i can use FileSystemWatcher to watch file created inside testing folder

Thanks,

Comment: test before if these folder exist otherwise create them

Comment: You're probably better off calling `Directory.CreateDirectory` before watching the folder. Watching every parent folder to check if the child folder exists looks to be more work than simply forcing the directory to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> case1: only contain drive C:\

Watch that directory for a "Logs" directory to be created, go to next case.

> case2: only contain folder C:\Logs

Watch that directory for a "CustomService" directory to be created, go to next case.

> case3: only contain folder C:\Logs\CustomService

Watch that directory for a "Testing" directory to be created, go to next case.

Or, [just create the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it).

Comment: Can watch fulle directory creation like below                                           new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\",@"Logs\CustomService\Testing\*.log")

Comment: No, you can't watch a directory that doesn't (partially) exist. You need to watch the parent directory until the subdirectory you're interested in is created.