# Trying to move files from one folder to another with subfolders C#

Tags: c#, create-directory

I want to reorganize all the photos from one folder into subfolders of another path, where I want to create new subfolders named with the file creation dates.

Example:

> photo1.png (creation date 12.02.2015)
>
> photo2.png (creation date 12.02.2015)
>
> photo3.png (creation date 13.02.2015)
>
> --> create two subfolders: "12-feb-2015" with photo1.png and photo2.png and "13-feb-2015" with photo3.png

I wrote the code for copying the photos into the other folder and create subfolder with the current date. But I don't know how to create the subfolders named after the creation date of the files.

```
public class SimpleFileCopy
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        string fileName = "*.png";
        string sourcePath = @"C:\tmp";
        string targetPath = @"U:\\";
        
        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        //string destFile = Path.Combine(Directory.CreateDirectory("U:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") , fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!Directory.Exists("U:\\" + Directory.CreateDirectory("U:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))))

        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("U:\\" + Directory.CreateDirectory("U:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")));
        }
        else
        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        {

            foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles(fileName))
            {
                try
                {
                    file.CopyTo(e.FullPath.Combine(targetPath + Directory.CreateDirectory("U:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")), file.Name));
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a folder does not exist, create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it)

Comment: Wait there...your already creating directory's? Your question make no sense then? What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: You are creating dirs based on DateTime.Now, is that the base of your question?

Comment: I didn't create the subdirectories. i need to create these named with the create date of the photos. I know it is a method GetCreationTime() but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having way to many `Directory.CreateDirectory` calls. Just enumerate your source folder files, then get the date with `file.CreationTime`, call `Directory.CreateDirectory` (no matter if it already exists) and then copy your file.

```
string fileName = "*.png";
string sourcePath = @"C:\tmp";
string targetPath = @"U:\";

foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath).GetFiles(fileName))
{
    var targetFolderName = file.CreationTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(targetPath, targetFolderName));
    file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(dir.FullName, file.Name), true);
}
```