# How to create a folder in bin/debug

Tags: c#, directory

I know how to create a file in bin/debug.

```
string file = "example"
StreamWriter outputStream = File.CreateText(file + ".txt");
```

But is it also possible to create a folder into bin/debug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a folder does not exist, create it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it)

Comment: `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory`

Comment: [Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("NewFolder");
```