# Changing the default desktop save location of iTextSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I'm looking everywhere in the internet but my code doesn't match the others. I have this

```
  string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fullname);
```

I can't have the `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop` to make it to `Documents/Files` How can I specify which folder my pdf document will be saved?

here is my full code.

```
string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fullname);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 40, 30);
PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();
    .
    .
    .
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but you can just set the value of `outputFile` to where ever you want it go be and the file will be written there. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey I tried what you said and I made this. `string outputFile ="C:\Users\Company\Documents\My Web Sites"` But it throws me an `UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled`??

Comment: That's because you didn't specify a file name in your `outputFile`, only the folder.

Comment: There! I did it! Thanks man. I forgot to add the filename. Should you or me answer this?

Comment: I think you should see @GeniusBraiNs answer first. He has the better way than just hardcoding the filepath which is very limiting. Unless that is not what you were actually after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you should be using:

```
string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), @"Documents/Files", fullname);
```

If your desired output folder isn't a subfolder of desktop, you can just remove the `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)` part and use whatever path you want. Don't forget to use escape the string (i.e. using "@"). And don't forget to combine the filename to the output folder path.

If it's not what you're after, then please provide more details.

Comment: But that's all the details there is to it. I tried what you suggest and it gives me `DirectoryNotFoundException` and it said that `Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\Company\Desktop\Documents\Files\fullname.pdf`

Comment: Please read this part of the answer: "If your desired output folder isn't a subfolder of desktop,..."

Comment: Oh okay yeah, sorry. I tried that and I ended up with this absolute path. `string outputFile = Path.Combine("C:/Users/Company/Downloads", fullname);` and it works. But what does the `@` is used for?

Comment: @Fiendcoder1, `DirectoryNotFoundException` means you have to create the directory first. You can do that by code

Comment: `string outputFile = Path.Combine("C:/Users/Company/Downloads", fullname);` would also throw the `DirectoryNotFoundException` excepion if the folder did not exist either. Making your application create the folder itself will make it more robust.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it

Comment: @Fiendcoder1, `@` is used to make a verbatim string instead of a regular string. check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312007/4934172) to know more. And you might also need to check [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) for what characters need to be escaped.