# Downloading file from url c# (Other questions didn't work with me)

Tags: c#, winforms

When i use other questions' answers i get a WebException and it crashes, here is the following code i tried:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png", @"C:\folder\stackoverflowlogo.png");
```

And I get a WebException when I click the button of the download, so anyone got a fix for this problem? I'm trying to download a file from a url without getting a WebException.

Comment: Yes, point to an existing domain. `i.stackoverflow.com` does not exist!

Comment: I concur with Patrick.

Comment: Already tried. I just wrote that code as an example.

Comment: So how are we able to help you if you just make up some code?

Comment: The url is:  http://download1417.mediafire.com/531vw6yc9v4g/sq90gpk3wrs8msi/DooMCrafT-V1.zip

Comment: So what is the exception you get?

Comment: It tells me "WebException was unhandled, An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll, additional information: an exception occurred during a WebClient Request"

Comment: What does the `InnerException` say? Come on, stop dripfeeding the information.

Comment: And what do you get when you open the page using a browser?

Comment: I don't know how to get that.

Comment: I start a download when i open the page.

Comment: In your example you use `C:\folder\ `. Does that folder exist and does your app have permission to write to it?

Comment: I get *Permission denied* when I run that. I guess you need to log on first.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The URL is fine for me, the permission is likely the destination folder.

Comment: I'll try change the folder.

Comment: I don't think so, it won't yield a `WebException` then @DavidG

Comment: Try something like `C:\Users\<your-user>\Downloads`

Comment: Okay guys, that worked! Thanks but can you tell me how to make it create a folder if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Everything in `WebClient` throws a `WebException`

Comment: That is sad @DavidG

Comment: [If a folder does not exist, create it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9065598/993547)

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's why I usually tell people to drop it and use `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle errors like this, so that you can easily debug through the cause of error.

Please go through Status values **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx)**, there is more to handle

```
try
        {           

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile({url},{filename to save});

            }               
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if(ex.Status==WebExceptionStatus.Timeout) //Timeout 
            {

            }
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure) //Connection error 
            {

            }
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure) //URL not valid
            {

            }
            if (ex.Response!= null)
            {
                if (((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    // error 404, do what you need to do

                }                   
            }               

        }
```