# How to update a folder if exist and if not exist create it during setup with winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-project

I am new to wimforms, I successfully create a set-up for my project. Also I added a folder to user's desktop in the file system. Folder is created after set-up, however I dont want it to be created if it already exist and it does that so I end up with two folders with same name after installation.  Is there any way to prevent that? I tryed all combinations of "always create" and "transitive" bool values. I ak working with c#. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a folder does not exist, create it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065598/if-a-folder-does-not-exist-create-it)

Comment: No, not unfortunatelly, since I am looking for automatic setup properties not code